# keep the shared object even after uninstalling the android app

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

Is there a way to save shared Objects even if the app is uninstalled ? I'm using flash and the app is for android devices.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a file on sd-card and save your Objects using an ObjectOutputStream. You will just need to implement the java.io.Seriealizable interface in your custom Objects.

The drawback of this solution is that every application can access your file and the user could possibly delete it.

Comment: thank Jan, but i don't want to save in sd-card because all users might not be using sd-card. I just want to save some data to check the expiry date and total time elapsed. And is there a way to this without using another software ?

Comment: I dont think so. The private resources of the app are getting purged completely with the uninstall. So the only possibilities are to use a file on filesystem (sdcard) or another application to persist your data. But even if the Smartphone doesnt have a adcard there should  always be some sort of external storage be available for apps even if its only emulated and effectively internally stored.